# Time zone in swift - NSDate

Tags: swift, timezone, nsdate

i'm using xCode 7.2.1 ad Swift2, writing fo iOS.

i did a function for converting a String to a NSDate and that's :

`class func StringToDateWithHour(data : String) -> NSDate
    {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "CET");
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        guard let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(data) else{
            return NSDate()
        }
        return date
    }`

I don't understand why i get back the UTC time, INSTEAD of CET time.
When i try to convert a string like : "2016-2-21 10:00:00" i get back 
"2016-2-21 09:00:00"    , one hour less.
Thank you.

Comment: All dates are just a point in time. You need to use NSDateFormatter to display your local time

Comment: You should return optional NSDate and return nil in case of failure

Comment: All you need is to get stringFromDate using the same date formatter

Comment: Ok thanks everybody. i add  "dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()" before the call and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that you want to convert 10 am CET to a NSDate. 
That correctly outputs 9 am UTC time (UTC is one hour behind CET time).

NSDate objects don't depend on time zones, they're just data from a particular point in time.

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).